# How to use a for-loop with an ode

Tags: r, for-loop, ode

I'm working on building a model based on Lotka-Volterra dynamics that includes a stochastic dispersion measure, with the goal of looking at population sizes over time as the relative density of the maladapted prey item increases.

I have a fully functioning base LV model. So far, I've tried putting the entire model in a loop and defining dispersion as a sequence.

This is my base model:

```
LVmod<-function(Time,State,Pars){
  with(as.list(c(State, Pars)),{
    ingestion1 <- ingP1 * P1 * P #ingestion maladapted
    ingestion2 <- ingP2 * P2 * P #ingestion residents
    ingestion3 <- ingS * S * p #source population

    growthprey1 <- rGrow1 * P1 * (1-((P1+P2)/K)) #mal
    growthprey2 <- rGrow2 * P2 * (1-((P2+P1)/K)) #res
    growthsource <- rGrowS * S * (1-(S/K2)) #source pop

    mortpred <- rMort * P #predator mortality
    mortpredS <- rMort * p #source pred mort
    migration <- S*.5 #dispersal from source pop

    dPrey1 <- growthprey1 - ingestion1 + migration #change in maladapted pop
    dPrey2 <- growthprey2 - ingestion2 # change in resident pop
    dSource <- growthsource - ingestion3 # source
    dPred <- (ingestion1+ingestion2)*assEff - mortpred #change in predator
    dpredS <- (ingestion3)*assEff - mortpredS #source predator

    return(list(c(dPrey1,dPred,dPrey2,dSource,dpredS)))
  })
}

pars <- c(ingP1 = 0.8,
          ingP2 = 0.2,
          ingS = 0.2,
          rGrow1 = 0.5,
          rGrow2 = 1.5,
          rGrowS = 1.5,
          rMort = 0.2,
          assEff = 0.8,
          K = 10,
          K2 = 15)
yini <- c(P1 = 1, P = 2, P2 = 1, S = 1, p = 2)
times <- seq(0,200,by=1)
out <- ode(yini,times,LVmod,pars)
```

This is the problem line:

```
migration <- S*.5 #dispersal from source pop
```

Currently, I have the value of dispersal set to .5. I would like to be able to have something like this:

```
migration <- S*dispersal
```

with dispersal varying randomly per iteration.

This is the beginning of the loop I've tried:

```
for (j in 2:200){
    disp=runif(200,0,1)
    LVmod<-function(Time,State,Pars){......
```

I'm wanting to produce a result that can be graphed as changing population sizes over time in relation to changing dispersal rates. Right now, if I run a loop, I get a large number of plots that have a single horizontal line.

Comment: What is the function `ode`?

Comment: ode solves a system of ordinary differential equations based on the model information you provide